# Delete rows based on more than one condition

Tags: excel, vba, macros

can you help me with the following code I made?

```
Sub DeleteRows()
Dim c As Range
Dim SrchRng

Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
Do
    Set c = SrchRng.Find("12345", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

End Sub

I have a chart with program codes in column A. I want to create a macro that will delete all rows with specific program codes: 12345, 541, 9099, etc.
The code I have can only refer to one value. I don't know how to add more. And on top of that, it will delete program codes with "12345" in it. For example, it will delete rows with the program code: 123456. Can we prevent it from doing that too?

P.S. not sure if it's a good idea to set the range like I did: A1:A65536. too big?

Thank you!

Comment: Check my anser and edit please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead iterate over the range. You also don't want to set the range that large if you don't have that much data.

```vb
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = last_row To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "12345" or _
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "541" or _
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = "9099" Then 
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm getting a Syntax error for these four rows:     
    
If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = '12345' or _
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = '541' or _
           ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = '9099' Then

I'm not sure why :S @bernie

Comment: Ah, please see edit. The single-quotes should be double-quotes.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you! I assume the code has the range iterated? @bernie

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the code iterates over the first column.

Answer (score 1):

This way you can go over the values inside the array with the values/strings you want to check inside the data:

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i
    Dim r
    Dim theValues(1 To 5)
    Dim SrchRng As Range

    theValues(1) = "1231"
    theValues(2) = "1232"
    theValues(3) = "1233"
    theValues(4) = "1234"
    theValues(5) = "1235"

    r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrchRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1))
    For Each i In theValues
        Do
            Set c = SrchRng.Find(i, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            'see the ", LookAt:=xlWhole" added, this way you can find just the Whole values.
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Edit #1**
As you ask in the comments, see the edit to: go over the data looking just for the complete values (you look for `91` not `910` or `1891`), then heres is my version if you want to put the values inside a range in a sheet, then you can add any value to be found.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i
    Dim r
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim a
    Dim theValues()
    Dim SrchRng As Range

    r = Range("T1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set rng = Range("T1", Cells(r, 20))

    For a = 1 To rng.Count 'in this range i store the values
        ReDim Preserve theValues(1 To a)
        theValues(a) = rng(a)
    Next a

    r = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SrchRng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(r, 1))
    For Each i In theValues
        Do
            Set c = SrchRng.Find(i, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great except it deleted other rows because cells included those values! Is there a way to make it specific for Column A? I like the list style! @Elbert