# How to Delete Rows If it doesn’t Contain Certain Text in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need a simple and easy to understand macro that is able to filter out all text that doesn't contain certain values text within a column and delete all rows, if it does contain the specified values those rows will NOT be deleted.

Based on the attachment provided I would like to delete all rows that does not contain **1997** and **2001** in **DOB column**.

when building this macro think of data on a larger scale that the number of columns is always changing, the first row will always need to stay the same.

[image: data]

i did not try any thing.

Comment: Here are few possible approaches using `VBA` please take a look for yourself and research: **[StackOverflow_Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+delete+rows+based+on+condition)**

Comment: None of the DOB fields contain 1997 AND 2001, do you mean *delete all rows that do not contain 1997 OR 2001* >

Comment: Here is one **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35848212/8162520)** btw with formula it would be like but it doesnt deletes instead extracts the data : `=FILTER(A2:D9,MMULT(N(LEFT(C2:C9,4)={"1997","2001"}),{1;1}))`

Comment: there are 4 field that contain 1997 and 2001 i want to delete all the rows that do not have 1997 or 2001 in column C(DOB)

Comment: I think as per the screenshot there are 6 field which have dob year as 1997 & 2001

Comment: yes i meant 6, i wont the macro to delete all the other e columns that does not contain 1997 and 2001

Comment: How many rows in the table fewer than or more than 1000 ?

Comment: more than 100 rows

Answer (score 0):

Select any row in your table, press Ctrl-t to 'insert table' (which is badly named, I know), filter out the rows you want to keep, delete the rows remaining, clear your filter to view the rows you kept.

I know this is a very brief, high level answer. Next time, try first and explain how you got stuck, the result you're getting, and the result you want.

Comment: This is what i have now, i have more criteria that i want to keep but this only allows me to add two options 


ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AY$17953").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "<>*1997*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*2001*"

Comment: We can only answer the questions you ask.  Please add criteria to your questions to prevent time spent answering them only to find out there's more detail

Answer (score 0):

You could add more keywords as needed.

Please try.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub demo()
    Dim c As Range, arrData, arrKey
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, bMatch As Boolean
    arrKey = Array("1997", "2001") ' key words list
    With Sheets("sheet1") ' update sheet name as needed
        arrData = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
        For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
            bMatch = False
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrKey)
                If InStr(arrData(i, 3), arrKey(j)) > 0 Then
                    bMatch = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            If Not bMatch Then
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    Set c = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set c = Application.Union(c, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            c.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

please try, without loop..

```
Option Explicit
Sub nbsd()
Dim p As Long, xx As Variant
p = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(3).Row
On Error Resume Next
xx = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Range("C2:C" & p), _
        Evaluate("SUBSTITUTE(MMULT(0+IF(--LEFT(C2:C" & p & ",4)={1997,2001},ROW(C2:C" & p & ")-1),{1;1}),0,"""")")), "")

[C2].Resize(UBound(xx), 1) = xx

Columns(3).SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```